# Why do we *restrict* to universes instead of *surrounding* us with them?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, philosophy, alternative-set-theories

In set theory and category theory one easily runs into the problem of size. For example Russell's paradox tells us that it is impossible to have consistent set theory allowing a set of all sets. Similarly a category with ALL limits/colimits is a poset, so a consistent theory allowing interesting categories should rather talk about having small limits/colimits.

The "formal" way around this problem is to add the *axiom of universes* to our favorite set theory, which allows us to restrict to certain *small sets*, which basically form a model of set theory within set theory. I do *not* doubt that this is useful or that it solves these problems! However it does not address the following issue:

When introducing material set theories (say ZFC) we usually define it as a first order theory satisfying some axioms. Likewise when introducing structural set theories (say ETCS) we define it speaking of a category of objects (called sets), which satisfies some axioms. In either way the *surrounding metatheory* (in which we define the notion of first order theory / category) makes use of notions such as *collection, equal, distinct, exists, for all, finite, infinite* etc. So in some sense our definitions make use of themselves, which makes me feel very uncomfortable, as it somewhat invalidates all formalism.

The only way around this problem I see is to state another axiom, that every model of our set theory is an internal model of another (larger) model ie. something like

- Every model of ZFC is a universe in a model of ZFC
- Every category satisfying ETCS is an internal category (ie. small category) in a category satisfying ETCS.

I could not find a treatment of this problem (maybe because I am unfamiliar with the literature), or someone mentioning my axiom. Why is this?

PS: Again, on the practical side it doesn't really matter, whether universes "go inside" or "go outside". Yet I think philosophically it does make a difference...

Comment: You’re not going to find a way around this. Your proposed axiom still relies on an external notion of what “a model of ZFC” is. Formal systems do not found themselves.

Comment: @KevinArlin I think the OP isn't necessarily trying to say that we could have a formal system without a foundation, but rather trying to say that if we want to study a formal system that we use as a foundation of mathematics, then we would want to have a larger formal system that behaves like our original system to study our original formal system in, and we'd want an ascending hierarchy of such systems. I could be interpreting the question wrongly, but it sounds like they want something like [Tarski's axiom.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%E2%80%93Grothendieck_set_theory)

Comment: Well I tried to use the notion of a model in the attempt to talk non-categorical language, but in this case I have to get back to categorical lingo. As I see it defining metacategory informal, then metacategory of sets, then internal category in a metacategory of sets my axiom would be that any metacategory is an internal category in a metacategory of sets. Why doesnt this close the loop? I mean tracing a circle you have to pick a point where to start, but as soon as you are running you cannot figure out from inside where you started...

Comment: @jgon thank you. This is precisely what I want to figure out. maybe I phrased it ambiguously...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me address the set theoretic part of your question.

First of all, the term "universe" is a bit loaded. It can mean either (1) just a mathematical universe, understood as a universe of sets, i.e. a model of set theory; or (2) a Grothendieck universe, specifically, especially in the context of category theory, which is a model of **second-order** set theory, which means that it is isomorphic with $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible cardinal $\kappa$, if you're unfamiliar with these notions, the key point to take forward is that this is a **very** special model of set theory which agrees with its metatheory on things like power sets, etc.

So right off the bat, we get that in the specific interpretation as a Grothendieck universe, it cannot be that every model of set theory is a universe in a larger model of set theory. But let's focus on the first meaning, simply "a model" (which raises the obvious question: why not just refer to it as a model?)

Nevertheless, these things are indeed studied, mostly in philosophy of set theory. You can read about the multiverse axioms, specifically in Hamkins' approach to the multiverse. Hamkins also has work on set theoretic potentialism, which you might want to read about.

Overall, if there is a proper class of inaccessible cardinals, you immediately get an ever growing hierarchy of universes that are even Grothendieck universes as well. This can be made stronger (e.g. require that "$\mathrm{Ord}$ is Mahlo") or weaker (e.g. require that simply every set is a transitive model of $\sf ZFC$", or even that there is a proper class of cardinals $\alpha$, such that $V_\alpha$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$; both of which are weaker than even a single inaccessible cardinal as far as consistency strength goes).

If my understanding of Grothendieck universes is correct, we actually do use them as you suggest. To make something "small", you must first envelope it by a larger universe. And since both universes agree on things like power sets, we get exactly what you're asking for.

One last thing worth pointing out, though, is that we can easily formalise all of the theories you mentioned, and more, in something like Peano arithmetic, or even Primitive Recursive Arithmetic, where there is no innate notion of "collection", rather this is meaning we assign—as people, as the readers and executors of mathematics—to the objects of set theory.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I think I have to digest quite a bit now :)